# AWS Drupal Headless CMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, headless-cms

Want to start implementing drupal on headless cms ( Drupal backend and frontend react)
May I have a proper documentation guiding me?
I have already asked for help on other but they are in general about server less which I am already aware about AWS services.
Like https://opensenselabs.com/blog/articles/serverless-computing-drupal

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is understanding drupal content. So you will need to create your content. It may variate a lot depending on your strategy.

Then, understand the drupal views. Most of decoupled headless drupal sites uses views to provide the API.

This can be done using JSON API module.

You can take this tutorial here https://drupalize.me/tutorial/add-rest-endpoint-views?p=3377

Comment: thanks.will follow this . if any questions will revert back to you.